# How to update a part of an object by using JS ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an object

```
{
    "_id" : "6QMR4A23KEXCFJDof",
    "userId" : "3Xb6teoWNnEMWKzgq"
    "title" : "My title",
    "lines" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "5eafc0186f0cc7c5c4bb1989",
            "text" : "First line...",
            "align" : "left"
        },
        {
            "id" : "eb1b5ef1212d2c0099716bd7",
            "text" : "Second line...",
            "align" : "left"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I update "text" of the "line" with id="eb1b5ef1212d2c0099716bd7" by using javascript ES6?
Thanks!

Comment: Why specifically ES6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the following way

```js
let obj = {
    "_id" : "6QMR4A23KEXCFJDof",
    "userId" : "3Xb6teoWNnEMWKzgq",
    "title" : "My title",
    "lines" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "5eafc0186f0cc7c5c4bb1989",
            "text" : "First line...",
            "align" : "left"
        },
        {
            "id" : "eb1b5ef1212d2c0099716bd7",
            "text" : "Second line...",
            "align" : "left"
        }
    ]
}

let idx = obj['lines'].findIndex((obj2) => obj2.id == "eb1b5ef1212d2c0099716bd7");

obj['lines'][idx].text = 'newVal';

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

if `obj` is your object:

```
obj.lines.forEach(l => {
    if (l.id === 'eb1b5ef1212d2c0099716bd7') {
        l.text = 'your new text';
    }
});
```

You probably want to use this code in a more generic function / refactor it to fit your purposes.

Comment: `obj.lines.find(a => a.id === 'eb1b5ef1212d2c0099716bd7').text = 'new text'`

Comment: I wouldn't suggest this, it can lead to errors if an element with that id doesn't exist - additionally, `Array.find` is not supported in IE.

Comment: Ofcourse you can add a check if find actually found an item before you try changing the text. I would use find over forEach though since it only loops until it finds the specific object.

Comment: good point, especially if the array is big - anyway in this case we are assuming that the id is unique, but we don't know the requirements of the OP

Comment: That's usually what ids are for: beeing unique identifiers...

Comment: I agree! it's _usually_ like that :D

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon "*`Array.find` is not supported in IE*", so are arrow functions...

Comment: @SergeK. correct. Those arrow functions can be easily converted to a regular function, while find cannot be that easily implemented in IE :) you can use polyfills, though.

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon The question is tagged `ecmascript-6`. Both `Array.prototype.find` and arrow functions are part of that specification

Comment: feel free to write an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You just want to filter your array using Array.filter and find the object with the supplied id. Then when you have that object you can just modify its properties. Below is an example

```
let obj = {
  _id: "6QMR4A23KEXCFJDof",
  userId: "3Xb6teoWNnEMWKzgq",
  title: "My title",
  lines: [
    {
      id: "5eafc0186f0cc7c5c4bb1989",
      text: "First line...",
      align: "left"
    },
    {
      id: "eb1b5ef1212d2c0099716bd7",
      text: "Second line...",
      align: "left"
    }
  ]
};

const updateLine = (id, property, newValue) => {
  let lineToUpdate = obj.lines.filter(line => line["id"] === id)[0][property] = newValue
}

updateLine("eb1b5ef1212d2c0099716bd7", "text", "newValue");
```